# Hybris SVG Integration

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

Has anyone had any issues integrating SVG files with Hybris front end? I have not found anything in the documentation in the wki or in here. It does not seem to be possible to use SVG files as graphics files. We have added this in the local.properties:

media.customextension.image.svg+xml=svg mediatype.by.fileextension.svg=image/svg+xml

Regards

Answer (score 1):

It may depend on what version of Hybris you're running or possibly how you're trying to add the code. I just tested on 5.2.1 and 5.5.1. I was able to use an SVG file as an asset from CSS by using

```
background: url(../images/mySvgImg.svg);
```

I was able to run

```
ant clean all
```

then

```
./hybrisserver.sh
```

And still get a clean build. I haven't plugged raw SVG data into the DOM, but I'm guessing Hybris may try to compile it in some way.

What error are you seeing when you run you try to build or start the server?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem. Solution, put this 2 line to your local.properties file:

`media.customextension.image.svg+xml=svg
mediatype.by.fileextension.svg=image/svg+xml`